# Is it possible to use an asterisk to display all the values of a single SSRS Parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to use an asterisk to display all the values of a single SSRS Parameter? So basically you have a parameter for first name. You type `*` and all the first names display. Or you can use exact name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an SSRS issue but how you interpret the parameters in your dataset query.

You could easily achieve this if you dataest query looked something like this simple example.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (FirstName = @pFirstName OR @pFirstName = '*')
```

This assumes your report parameter is called `pFirstName`

Comment: Thanks you Alan!